# Why button Widths are conflicts in UINavigationbar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, rightbarbuttonitem

I have a button inside UINavigation 
Bar Button Item [image]

This is my expectation but really what happens is [image] that button width getting depressed ,how to over come from this constant width ? any idea friends .

Comment: you have drag and drop UIButton in navigationbar ? or programatically set it ? check your UIButton size.

Comment: in this place use UIbarbuttonItem on right side

Comment: drag and drop from storyboard @BadalShah

Comment: ok then check you UIButton frame size.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik(doodleblue) bro you are correct,you answered many question for me thank you :)

Comment: @KishoreKumar -- welcome my bro..

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to increase the width of the UIButton in the Size Inspector?

[image]

Comment: make sure that the button itself is selected, not the Bar Button Item

Answer (score 0):

Set your button as rightBarButtonItem programatically.

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightbutton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button Title here" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = settingButton;
```